# Is there any way to get s3 uri from aws web console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I want to download *a directory* from my s3.
When I need *a file*, the s3 management console (aws web console) allows me to download it, but when *a directory*, I have to use aws-cli, like:

```
$ aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/mydirectory/ . --recursive
```

My question is: Is there any way to get the s3 uri (`s3://mybucket/mydirectory/`) from s3 management console?
It's URL is available, but it is slightly different from s3 URI required by aws-cli. I could not find any menu to get the uri.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(self-answer)

Because it seems there was no such way, I have created [one](https://github.com/keisuke-nakata/aws-cli-s3-url2uri):

```
pip install aws-s3-url2uri
```

And command `aws_s3_url2uri` will be available after installation.

This command internally converts the web console URLs to S3 URIs, so works with URLs and URIs and local paths:

```
aws_s3_url2uri ls "https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home?region=<regionname>#&bucket=mybucket&prefix=mydir/mydir2/"
```

calls

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/mydir/mydir2/
```

internally.

Answer (score 63):

No, it is not displayed in the console. However, it is simply:

```
s3://<bucket-name>/<key>
```

Directories are actually part of the `key`. For example, `foo.jpg` stored in an `images` directory will actually have a key (filename) of `images/foo.jpg`.

Comment: I am not able to figure out what would be the key of my s3 bucket. How do I get that from aws console or otherwise.

Comment: @GAURAVSRIVASTAVA There is no "key" to a bucket. There is simply the bucket name. The "Key" is the name of an object (think of it as a filename). The Key includes the full path within the filename (eg `invoices/2019-02.txt`).

Answer (score 4):

To convert an S3 URL displayed in the console such as `https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/my-bucket-name/filename` to an S3 URI, remove the `https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/` portion and replace it with `s3://`, like so:

```
s3://my-bucket-name/filename
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this feature is now available in the AWS Web Console.

It is accessible in two ways:

- Selecting the checkbox next to the file and clicking on "Copy S3 URI" button.

  [image]
- Clicking on the file, and clicking on the "Copy S3 URI" button on the top right.

  [image]

Answer (score 3):

You can get the value from the console by selecting the file in the console. Choose **Copy path** on the **Overview** tab to copy the S3:// link to the object.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get the S3-URI for a proper *key*/*file* in the console, by selecting the key and clicking on the <kbd>Copy path</kbd> button, this will place the s3-URI for the file on the clipboard.

However, directories are not keys as such but just key prefixes, so this will not work for them.

Comment: what do you mean by key? The name of my s3 bucket is 'embedded-videos`, but I do not see what is the key on my aws console.

Comment: @GAURAVSRIVASTAVA https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingObjects.html

Comment: @GAURAVSRIVASTAVA yes the key is the object name.

Answer (score 0):

You may fail to get s3uri if you are created a new bucket.
`You can get s3uri after creating a new folder in your bucket >> select check box to the newly created folder >> then copy the s3uri that appears at the top`.